# Positioning chemfig structures in TikZ nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, chemfig

With the following MWE (well not quite M!) I don't understand why, when I change from an ellipse box to a rectangle box (by uncommenting the corresponding lines), the molecule are shifted out of the boxes.

```
\documentclass[border = 0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{calc, arrows, decorations.pathmorphing}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\newcommand{\molA}[1]{\chemfig[line width=0.2pt][scale=#1]{[:45]HO-[:-30]-[:30]-[:-30]O-[:30]-[:-30]-[:30]O-[:-30]-[:30]-[:-30]O-[:30]-[:-30]-[:30]O-[:-30]-[:30]-[:-30]O-[:30]-[:-30]-[:30]OH}}
\newcommand{\molB}[1]{\chemfig[line width=0.2pt][scale=#1]{H-[:-30](=[:-90]O)-[:30]O-[:-30]-[:30]-[:-30]O-[:30]-[:-30]-[:30]O-[:-30]-[:30]-[:-30]O-[:30]-[:-30]-[:30]O-[:-30]-[:30]-[:-30]O-[:30](=[:90]O)-[:-30]H}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% starting dots
\fill[fill=blue] (0.0,1.9) circle (1pt);
\fill[fill=orange] (0.0,1.7) circle (1pt);
\fill[fill=red] (0.0,1.5) circle (1pt);
\fill[fill=green] (0.0,1.3) circle (1pt);
\fill[fill=purple] (0.0,1.1) circle (1pt);

\filldraw[draw=blue,fill=blue!10] (3.0,2.7) ellipse [x radius=55pt,y radius=6pt] node[color=black] (A) {\molA{0.2}};
\filldraw[draw=orange,fill=orange!10] (3.5,2.2) ellipse [x radius=55pt,y radius=6pt] node[color=black] (B) {\molA{0.2}};
\filldraw[draw=red,fill=red!10] (3.0,1.7) ellipse [x radius=55pt,y radius=6pt] node[color=black] (C) {\molA{0.2}};
% ellipse boxes
\filldraw[draw=green,fill=green!10] (3.5,0.8) ellipse [x radius=55pt,y radius=16pt] node[color=black] (D) {\molB{0.2}};
\filldraw[draw=purple,fill=purple!10] (3.0,-0.4) ellipse [x radius=55pt,y radius=16pt] node[color=black] (E) {\molB{0.2}};
%rectangle boxes
%\filldraw[draw=green,fill=green!10,rounded corners=5] (1.5,0.5) rectangle (5.5,1.1) node[color=black] (D) {\molB{0.2}};
%\filldraw[draw=purple,fill=purple!10,rounded corners=5] (1.0,-0.7) rectangle (5.0,-0.1) node[color=black] (E) {\molB{0.2}};

% arrows
\begin{scope}[thick,>=latex,->]
 \draw[color=blue] (0.0,1.9) -- (A);
 \draw[color=orange] (0.0,1.7) -- (B);
 \draw[color=red] (0.0,1.5) -- (C);
 \draw[color=green] (0.0,1.3) -- (D);
 \draw[color=purple] (0.0,1.1) -- (E);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

With the ellipse boxes, it's OK,
[image]

but with the rectangle boxes, it's out !
[image]

Any hint ?

Answer (score 2):

Use the node itself as a container. The problem with the original approach is that the current position after an ellipse is the center of the ellipse, whereas after a rectangle it is the top right corner.

```
\node[draw=green, fill=green!10, rounded corners=5] (D) at (3.5,0.8)  {\molB{0.2}};
\node[draw=purple,fill=purple!10,rounded corners=5] (E) at (3.0,-0.4) {\molB{0.2}};
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[border = 0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{calc, arrows, decorations.pathmorphing}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\newcommand{\molA}[1]{\chemfig[line width=0.2pt][scale=#1]{[:45]HO-[:-30]-[:30]-[:-30]O-[:30]-[:-30]-[:30]O-[:-30]-[:30]-[:-30]O-[:30]-[:-30]-[:30]O-[:-30]-[:30]-[:-30]O-[:30]-[:-30]-[:30]OH}}
\newcommand{\molB}[1]{\chemfig[line width=0.2pt][scale=#1]{H-[:-30](=[:-90]O)-[:30]O-[:-30]-[:30]-[:-30]O-[:30]-[:-30]-[:30]O-[:-30]-[:30]-[:-30]O-[:30]-[:-30]-[:30]O-[:-30]-[:30]-[:-30]O-[:30](=[:90]O)-[:-30]H}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% starting dots
\fill[fill=blue] (0.0,1.9) circle (1pt);
\fill[fill=orange] (0.0,1.7) circle (1pt);
\fill[fill=red] (0.0,1.5) circle (1pt);
\fill[fill=green] (0.0,1.3) circle (1pt);
\fill[fill=purple] (0.0,1.1) circle (1pt);

\filldraw[draw=blue,fill=blue!10] (3.0,2.7) ellipse [x radius=55pt,y radius=6pt] node[color=black] (A) {\molA{0.2}};
\filldraw[draw=orange,fill=orange!10] (3.5,2.2) ellipse [x radius=55pt,y radius=6pt] node[color=black] (B) {\molA{0.2}};
\filldraw[draw=red,fill=red!10] (3.0,1.7) ellipse [x radius=55pt,y radius=6pt] node[color=black] (C) {\molA{0.2}};
\node[draw=green,fill=green!10,rounded corners=5] (D) at (3.5,0.8) {\molB{0.2}};
\node[draw=purple,fill=purple!10,rounded corners=5] (E) at (3.0,-0.4) {\molB{0.2}};
% arrows
\begin{scope}[thick,>=latex,->]
 \draw[color=blue] (0.0,1.9) -- (A);
 \draw[color=orange] (0.0,1.7) -- (B);
 \draw[color=red] (0.0,1.5) -- (C);
 \draw[color=green] (0.0,1.3) -- (D);
 \draw[color=purple] (0.0,1.1) -- (E);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** Following the suggestion of @Guilherme, here is a version using elliptic nodes.

```
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
...
\node[draw=blue,  fill=blue!10,  ellipse,inner sep=1pt] (A) at (3.0, 2.7) {\molA{0.2}};
\node[draw=orange,fill=orange!10,ellipse,inner sep=1pt] (B) at (3.5, 2.2) {\molA{0.2}};
\node[draw=red,   fill=red!10,   ellipse,inner sep=1pt] (C) at (3.0, 1.7) {\molA{0.2}};
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[border = 0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{calc, arrows, decorations.pathmorphing,shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\newcommand{\molA}[1]{\chemfig[line width=0.2pt][scale=#1]{[:45]HO-[:-30]-[:30]-[:-30]O-[:30]-[:-30]-[:30]O-[:-30]-[:30]-[:-30]O-[:30]-[:-30]-[:30]O-[:-30]-[:30]-[:-30]O-[:30]-[:-30]-[:30]OH}}
\newcommand{\molB}[1]{\chemfig[line width=0.2pt][scale=#1]{H-[:-30](=[:-90]O)-[:30]O-[:-30]-[:30]-[:-30]O-[:30]-[:-30]-[:30]O-[:-30]-[:30]-[:-30]O-[:30]-[:-30]-[:30]O-[:-30]-[:30]-[:-30]O-[:30](=[:90]O)-[:-30]H}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% starting dots
\fill[fill=blue] (0.0,1.9) circle (1pt);
\fill[fill=orange] (0.0,1.7) circle (1pt);
\fill[fill=red] (0.0,1.5) circle (1pt);
\fill[fill=green] (0.0,1.3) circle (1pt);
\fill[fill=purple] (0.0,1.1) circle (1pt);

\node[draw=blue,  fill=blue!10,  ellipse,inner sep=1pt] (A) at (3.0, 2.7) {\molA{0.2}};
\node[draw=orange,fill=orange!10,ellipse,inner sep=1pt] (B) at (3.5, 2.2) {\molA{0.2}};
\node[draw=red,   fill=red!10,   ellipse,inner sep=1pt] (C) at (3.0, 1.7) {\molA{0.2}};
\node[draw=green, fill=green!10, rounded corners=5]     (D) at (3.5, 0.8) {\molB{0.2}};
\node[draw=purple,fill=purple!10,rounded corners=5]     (E) at (3.0,-0.4) {\molB{0.2}};
% arrows
\begin{scope}[thick,-latex]
 \draw[color=blue] (0.0,1.9) -- (A);
 \draw[color=orange] (0.0,1.7) -- (B);
 \draw[color=red] (0.0,1.5) -- (C);
 \draw[color=green] (0.0,1.3) -- (D);
 \draw[color=purple] (0.0,1.1) -- (E);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: OK, it is a good solution which gives the expected result. Thanks!

Comment: @DRi, There are Ellipse shape nodes as well (library `shapes.geometric`). You can use them instead of drawing the Ellipses, although they give weird inner spacing sometimes.

Comment: @DRi The advantage of using the node itself is that when you draw a line, tikz knows by itself where the border of the node is and where the line/arrow has to stop.

Comment: @Guilherme Z. Santos, I may try this option sometimes. Thanks!

Comment: I've added a version using elliptic nodes, to illustrate the proposal of @GuilhermeZ.Santos .

Comment: @gernot, do you know why tikz makes the elliptic nodes so wide? it seems to me that `inner sep` is not doing anything there (for the spacing in the `x` direction), the node could definetely be smaller, It seems to me...

Comment: @GuilhermeZ.Santos `inner sep` just makes the ellipse smaller a bit, but doesn't change its proportions. No, I don't know how the tikz library computes the parameters of the ellipse. Maybe there is some way to reduce its width (and make it a bit higher instead), but I haven't yet found it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (notice the addition of `pos=0.5` in the nodes):

```
\filldraw[draw=green,fill=green!10,rounded corners=5] (1.5,0.5) rectangle (5.5,1.1) node[color=black,pos=0.5] (D) {\molB{0.2}};
\filldraw[draw=purple,fill=purple!10,rounded corners=5] (1.0,-0.7) rectangle (5.0,-0.1) node[color=black,pos=0.5] (E) {\molB{0.2}};
```

The manual (page 235, version 3.01) has this to say about `pos`:

> ```
> /tikz/pos=⟨fraction⟩ (no default)
> ```
>
> When this option is given, the node is not anchored on the last coordinate. Rather, it is anchored on some point on the line from the previous coordinate to the current point. The ⟨fraction⟩ dictates how “far” on the line the point should be. A ⟨fraction⟩ of 0 is the previous coordinate, 1 is the current one, everything else is in between. In particular, 0.5 is the middle.

[image: Better placement of chemfig molecule.]

Comment: +1. Aside from that you can use the node between the path operation and the coordinate, in that case the node automatically receives the `pos=.5` option (e.g. `\draw (0,0) rectangle node{A} (1,1);`). Also, a shorthand for `pos=.5` is `midway`, they mean the same.

Comment: I works fine. I didn't know this option `pos=` . This solution is perhaps 'dirtier' than the second one, but it may be very useful for some manual fine adjustments. Thanks!